# session cookie asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c, visual-studio-2010

please need help . actully i want to pass the info from page 1 to 2 using cookie but every i click buttom add to set a new cookie ....no just set the same nae and modify value . and read all cookie as list i dont know if u will understaidn what i want !!

here my code

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />


        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpCookie Cookie = new HttpCookie("result");            

            Cookie["text1"] = TextBox1.Text;
            Cookie["text2"] = TextBox2.Text;
            Cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
            Response.Cookies.Add(Cookie);
           Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");


        }



        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            HttpCookie Cookie = Request.Cookies["result"];
            if (Cookie != null)
            {

                Ldonate.Text = Cookie["text1"] ;
                Litem.Text = Cookie["text2"] ;
}
```

Comment: i don't know if i will understand either. Just clarify your question, and remove the irrelevant tag. For example, I doubt it has anything to do with C.

Answer (score 0):

`Ldonate.Text = Request.Cookies["result"]["text1"];
 Litem.Text = Request.Cookies["result"]["text2"];`
this is how you can access to cookies